Tax Implications of exercising both NSOs and ISOs
My partner and I are trying to figure out the correct tax strategy to exercise the largest amount of ISOs without triggering Alternative Minimum Tax (AMT).
Situation

Filing Status: Single
Strike Price: $20
FMV: $200
W2 Income: $150,000
NSOs: 1000
ISOs: 1000

Understanding
From what I can gather from other posts and resources on the internet, the exercise of NSOs adds the bargain element as regular income to the current year. That change would increase the Adjusted Gross Income (AGI) value in your Tentative Minimum Tax (TMT) calculation letting you exercise a greater number of Incentive Stock Options (ISOs) in that year.
Question
Is this understanding of how AGI is calculated for the purposes of TMT correct, or would we risk ending up with a large AMT bill? We are going to book a meeting with a tax advisor, but wanted to confirm my understanding first.
I've been using an online AMT calculator to play around with some of the values.

What's TMT in this context? What country are you asking about? Is it the US tax law?

@littleadv TMT = tentative minimum tax

Avoiding AMT here feels like the wrong goal. I would go with "minimizing tax liability" for your specific scenario (including expected hold times). If you pay 30% without AMT and 25% with AMT, I'd go with AMT. Granted AMT is a pain in the neck, but AMT credit is real and in most cases you get it back over time anyway.

A tax advisor will be helpful, but you may also want to evaluate the overall impact this decision will have on your financial situation with a qualified financial planner. Don't make decisions purely to avoid AMT. As Craig said, there's a lot more to it than just AMT, and future years come into play with the minimum tax credit (MTC) if you incur AMT from ISO exercises as well.
The NSO exercise spread ($180,000 in your example) adds to both regular income (AGI) and AMT income (AMTI). This often, but not always, means that you'll be able to exercise more ISOs before triggering AMT.
A couple things that can affect this are:

If you end up in the 10%/12%/22%/24% tax bracket for the year, additional ordinary income usually reduces the amount of ISOs you can exercise under AMT slightly (since AMT brackets are 26% and 28%).
If you end up in or above the AMT exemption phaseout threshold ($1,218,700 MFJ, $609,350 for all other filers in 2024), the amount of ISOs you can exercise before triggering AMT might decrease because your AMT exemption (think standard deduction but for AMT) is reduced.

For example, if you file jointly and have combined wages of $200,000 (no other income or deductions), adding $180,000 of NSO spread will reduce your AMT threshold for ISO exercises by about $19,000. The attached image shows how the additional spread (in wages) means AMT is triggered closer to $21k of ISO spread vs. $40k of ISO spread (AMT shows as $1 to illustrate being right above the threshold).
Keep in mind that even if you don't trigger AMT from an ISO exercise or you're in a situation where adding NSO spread increases your AMT threshold, additional NSO exercises will increase your total tax bill because the exercise spread is taxed as ordinary income (W-2 compensation). See 2nd image.

Example of additional taxes owed simply because of exercising NSOs:


Thank you for the very in depth answer! I forgot to mention in the post originally that we're both filing individually, and have MCT from previous years we're using up still. The year we had exercised too many ISOs we got hit with a large tax bill so were trying to avoid that again, but your note that we could end up paying more tax overall is a good point.
Another consideration for us is that we want to try to diversify our holdings, and are placing larger importance on that than trying to reduce our tax bill.

I'm not following why exercising NSOs, and therefore increasing your regular tax AGI, would allow you to exercise more ISOs without paying AMT. Of course regular tax and AMT can interact in odd ways, so I can't rule it out completely.
But I put your info into Excel 1040, which could be extremely helpful for your situation. I assumed 2024, married filing jointly, $150k of W-2 income with no pre-tax deductions, no other income, and taking the standard deduction. It looks like you can exercise about 260 ISOs until AMT starts kicking in. I then added exercising 100 NSOs, or 1000 NSOs, and you will still be paying AMT.
I'm also dubious about exercising NSOs just to be able to exercise more ISOs. Exercising NSOs has significant, permanent tax consequences, while the AMT you pay due to exercising ISOs you should eventually get refunded back in years you don't owe AMT.

Stan's post was along the lines of my thinking, but it seems like there are some exceptions. Thank you for the 1040 resource, it's very thorough.
